# NHibernate/ASP.NET textarea binding issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, nhibernate, textarea, modelstate

i am developing an application in MVC3 using nhibernate.
It is an Question-Answer Forum where on the first Page the Questions are displayed as link along with a textarea at the bottom to enter the Question.
I have made a class and an mapping file for the same.
Question class:

```
public class Questions
{
    public virtual int QuestionID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual string Question { get; set; }

    public virtual int CreatedBy{ get; set; }

    public virtual DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

    public virtual int ModifiedBy { get; set; }

    public virtual DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }

    public virtual char Deleted { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Answers> Answer { get; set; }
}
```

and this is the Mapping File:

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly ="Core" namespace ="Core.Model" >
<class name ="Questions" >

<id name="QuestionID">
  <generator class="native" />
</id>

<property name="Question"/>
<property name="CreatedBy"  />
<property name="CreatedDate"  />
<property name="ModifiedBy"  />
<property name="ModifiedDate"  />
<property name="Deleted"/>
<bag name="Answer" table="ANSWERS" lazy="true">
  <key column="FKQuestionID"/>
  <one-to-many class="Core.Model.Answers"/>
</bag>
```

While saving inside the controller i have wriiten this:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Question_Page(Questions ques, string PostyourQuestion)
    {
            ques.Question = PostyourQuestion;
            ques.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
            ques.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
            ques.CreatedBy = 101;
            ques.ModifiedBy = 101;
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                new QuestionService().SaveOrUpdateQuestions(ques);
            }
            return View(new QuestionService().GetAllQuestions());
  }
```

Inside View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Question_Page","QuestionAnswer",FormMethod.Post))
{ 
@Html.ValidationSummary(false) 
<ul>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <li>@Html.ActionLink(item.Question, "Answer_Page", new { Id = item.QuestionID}) </li>
}
   </ul>

 <br />
<h2><label for="PostyourQuestion:">Post your Question:</label></h2>
 @Html.TextArea("PostyourQuestion")    
<br /><br />
<input type="submit"/>
```

}

Now the problem is it is not saving the value entered inside "PostyourAnswer" textarea.even if enter value in it.if i remove the Required Attribute it will save the data within the table but i need to provide some validation when the user does not enter data..Please help me how to go about it

Answer (score 0):

In your ViewModel/ Model, Add a MultilineText attribute to tour Question Property so that it will be rendered as a text area when.

```
[Required]
[DataType (DataType.MultilineText)]
public virtual string Question { get; set; }
```

Change  `@Html.TextArea("PostyourQuestion")`
to

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Question)
```

Comment: hey But i am using this model IEnumerable<Core.Model.Questions> as my model type so wont be able to use Html.EditorFor(Model.Question)
dats y i was using input type

Comment: Actually, the EditorFor parameter needs to be a lambda: `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Question)`

Comment: @esker u are right but as i said above i m using IEnumerable so i cant use this..can u plz suggest me some other way of dealing this!!!

Comment: @esker : Thanks Esker. I missed that. Updated my answer now.

Answer (score 0):

Create a "View Model" - a special class holding properties needed for your view, and use this as your view's model.

E.g.

```
public class AddQuestionViewModel 
{
   public List<Question> Questions { get; set; }

   [Required]
   [DataType (DataType.MultilineText)]
   public string QuestionToAsk{ get; set; }
}
```

Then your view would look like

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Question_Page","QuestionAnswer",FormMethod.Post))
{ 
@Html.ValidationSummary(false) 
<ul>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <li>@Html.ActionLink(item.Question, "Answer_Page", new { Id = item.QuestionID}) </li>
}
   </ul>

 <br />
<h2><label for="PostyourQuestion:">Post your Question:</label></h2>
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.QuestionToAsk)   
<br /><br />
<input type="submit"/>
```

and your controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Question_Page(AddQuestionViewModel viewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {

        var ques = new Question();
        ques.Question = viewModel.QuestionToAsk;
        ques.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
        ques.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
        ques.CreatedBy = 101;
        ques.ModifiedBy = 101;


        new QuestionService().SaveOrUpdateQuestions(ques);
    }
    return View(new QuestionService().GetAllQuestions());
}
```